# Z-index not working on children within parent

Tags: html, css

I know there have been lots of questions about z-index, but I looked through them and still don't see what I'm missing here.  It must be something simple I'm just overlooking.  I've had z-index work on other elements.  Someone help me out here:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.bottom1,
.bottom2 {
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
.bottom2 {
  float: right;
}
.top {
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="bottom1">hello</div>
    <div class="top">again</div>
    <div class="bottom2">bye</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

I have the JSfiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/slabicht2/drj0qLt2/

Thanks

Comment: what exactly "isn't working?"

Comment: I have the same question as jbutler483. You say the 'top' div should have a z-index of 6 and to appear on top, and it does.  Is this not what you're going for? Edit: I went into your fiddle and messed around with z-index values and everything appears to be working as expected.

Comment: They are still stacking...I need the top box to appear above bottom boxes 1 and 2 which are on the left and right side of the parent div respectively.  The top box will be centered in the parent div above the other two.

Comment: I updated the JSfiddle to this to try and demonstrate my problem betters...http://jsfiddle.net/slabicht2/drj0qLt2/1/...thank you again for your help.

Comment: That's no longer a problem with the z-index attribute, that's a problem with your positioning.

Comment: I see...I just needed to move the top div to the last position...thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your z-index, it's your positioning.

If I understand correctly you want your elements to have ablsolute positioning and be under your 'top' div.

EDIT: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/drj0qLt2/2/)

Change your CSS to

```
.bottom1, .bottom2 {
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: yellow;
    height: 50px;
}

.bottom2 {
    right: 0;    
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion...but based on your comment above..I played with the physical position and floats.  I moved the middle div to the last position and then gave the first div a float left and second a float right.  Then I didn't need to use absolute positioning...Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: I try to use floats as little as possible, but I'm glad I was able to help.